# How do I set up a HTTP to HTTPS redirection for a specific domain in lighttpd?

Tags: regex, ssl, redirect, lighttpd

I would like to redirect specific domains from http to the corresponding https address in lighttpd. I tried out the tutorial on the lighttpd page but there it is not written for a specific domain. This is what I want:

```
$HTTP["host"] =~ "secure.example.com" {
     server.document-root = "/var/www/secure.example.com"
     // IF NOT SSL, REDIRECT TO SSL
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use port detection to be sure that your user come from an HTTP URL

```
$SERVER["socket"] == ":80" {
  $HTTP["host"] =~ "example.org" {
    url.redirect = ( "^/(.*)" => "https://example.org/$1" )
    server.name                 = "example.org" 
  }
}
```

---

**Resources :**

- [lighttpd.net - How to redirect HTTP requests to HTTPS](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/wiki/1/HowToRedirectHttpToHttps)